# how to concat multiple data in mysql with new line and serial no?

Tags: mysql

I want to concat name , phone and show it into info column with new line and serial. in case of missing name phone will take serial 1.+84757 and so on.thanks in advance.

[image: table]

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: That kind of formatting would be done in the calling application. SQL doesn't format the output like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try by using `CONCAT_WS` may  work, but serial no will not assign below query

```
SELECT name,phone,CONCAT_WS('\n',name,phone) as info from your_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

i use GROUP_CONCAT and succeed with '\n' or br separator

```
SELECT sl, name, phone, GROUP_CONCAT(t.info SEPARATOR "<br>") info FROM your_table t WHERE t.name='jake' GROUP BY t.sl
```